# About calling an subclass' overriding method when casted to its superclass

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
#include <iostream>

class Vehicle { 
public:
    void greet() {
        std::cout << "Hello, I'm a vehicle";
    }
};

class Car : public Vehicle { 
public:
    void greet() {
        std::cout << "Hello, I'm a car";
    }
};

class Bike : public Vehicle { 
public:
    void greet() {
        std::cout << "Hello, I'm a bike";
    }
};

void receiveVehicle(Vehicle vehicle) {
    vehicle.greet();
}

int main() {
    receiveVehicle(Car());
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to send a parameter of type `Vehicle` to a function, which calls `greet()`.

`Car` and `Bike` are subclasses of `Vehicle`. They overwrite `greet()`.

However, I'm getting "Hello, I'm a vehicle".

I suppose that this is because `receiveVehicle` receives a parameter of type `Vehicle` instead of a specific subclass like `Car` or `Bike`. But that's what I want: I want this function to work with any subclass of `Vehicle`.

Why am I not getting the expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

**1)** When you call `receiveVehicle(Car());` the parameter is accepted by value. This means that an issue related to [slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) occurs - a default copy constructor of `Vehicle` is called which constructs a `Vehicle` from your car. Change to pointers or references to make it work as you indented.

For example:

```
void receiveVehicle(Vehicle& vehicle) {
    vehicle.greet();
}

int main() {
    Car aCar;
    receiveVehicle(aCar);
    return 0;
}
```

**2)** Polymorphic calls are only made when base method is marked with the `virtual` keyword. So you need to make `greet` virtual:

```
class Vehicle { 
public:
    virtual void greet() {
        std::cout << "Hello, I'm a vehicle";
    }
};
```

For strictness you can also use `const` as appropriate:

```
class Vehicle { 
public:
    virtual void greet() const {   //change it also in subclasses
        std::cout << "Hello, I'm a vehicle";
    }
};

void receiveVehicle(const Vehicle& vehicle) {
    vehicle.greet();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Only pointers and references can be polymorphic. You are experiencing **slicing**, where a base class is constructed from a derived class and loses its identity as a derived and all the extra data members.

**tl;dr**: Change your function to accept a `Vehicle&` (and make the parameter a non-temporary) and it will work fine. Also, by default functions are non-virtual, so you'll need to add the word `virtual` before the function definition in the base class, like `virtual void greet() { ... }` (thanks Diego for noticing).

> **Long explanation**:
>
> Remember that when you have a value, the compiler must know how much memory to allocate for it. Derived classes can be bigger than base classes, so when you construct a base class from a derived, it loses (slices off) the data that the derived class carries, and only the base class data is preserved.
>
> Even though your derived classes have no members and are therefore no bigger than the base class, the compiler knows that a value can't be polymorphic, so it doesn't bother to look up the virtual function from the vtable of the instance. It will just call the function directly, resulting in static (non-polymorphic) behavior, and the base class function is called.
>
> Think of what would happen if the compiler did call the virtual one: the `this` pointer would point to an object that didn't have the derived data in it because it got sliced off, and when the function tried to access the derived member variables, they wouldn't be there!

Comment: In addition to your answer, the method must be declared virtual in the base class. The OP's code is missing that.

Answer (score 1):

```
void receiveVehicle(const Vehicle &vehicle) {
    vehicle.greet();
}
// Make your `greet` method `const`
```

Pass it by reference *(or pointer if you know about the risks)* to let polymorphism works. Otherwise `Car` will be sliced to `Vehicle`.